# Customizing PFLogInViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, heroku, parse-server, pfloginviewcontroller

When using `PFLogInViewController` I would like to have a "Sign up" button in case a user comes and has no account yet.
But even though  I have set up `PFSignUpFieldsSignUpButton` in the line

```
[myLogInViewController setFields:PFLogInFieldsUsernameAndPassword|
    PFLogInFieldsDismissButton|PFSignUpFieldsSignUpButton];
```

It only makes a "Log In" button appear and no "Sign up" button.

What do I need to do?

Here the relevant sequence of code:

```
// CustomLogInViewController is a subclass of PFLogInViewController.
CustomLogInViewController *myLogInViewController = [[CustomLogInViewController alloc] init];
[myLogInViewController setFields:PFLogInFieldsUsernameAndPassword
 | PFLogInFieldsDismissButton|PFSignUpFieldsSignUpButton];
```

Comment: Where do you call that method?

Comment: Right after instantiating the PFLogInViewController. I edited the original post to add the sequence of code.

Comment: And where is all of this code? what does viewDidLoad / willAppear look like on your CustomLogInViewController?

Comment: The answer was simple as you can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone has a similar problem at some point. This is what I had done wrong. Instead of:

```
[myLogInViewController setFields:PFLogInFieldsUsernameAndPassword|
    PFLogInFieldsDismissButton|PFSignUpFieldsSignUpButton];
```

It should be:

> ```
> [myLogInViewController setFields:PFLogInFieldsUsernameAndPassword|
>  PFLogInFieldsDismissButton|PFLogInFieldsLogInButton|PFLogInFieldsSignUpButton];
> ```